# Using a cache as a layer in front of a database

Tags: java, caching, guava, jcache, caffeine

I'm working on some back-end service which is asynchronous in nature. That is, we have multiple jobs that are ran asynchronously and results are written to some record.

This record is basically a class wrapping an `HashMap` of results (keys are `job_id`).

The thing is, I don't want to calculate or know in advance how many jobs are going to run (if I knew, I could `cache.invalidate()` the key when all the jobs has already been completed)

Instead, I'd like to have the following scheme:

1. Set an expiry for new records (i.e. `expireAfterWrite`)
2. On expiry, write (actually `upsert`) the record the database
3. If a cache miss occurs, `load()` is called to fetch the record from the database (if not found, create a new one)

**The problem:** 
I tried to use Caffeine cache but the problem is that records aren't expired at the exact time they were supposed to. I then read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26045917/10255450) for Guava's Cache and I guess a similar mechanism works for Caffeine as well.

So the problem is that a record can "wait" in the cache for quite a while, even though it was already completed. Is there a way to overcome this issue? That is, is there a way to "encourage" the cache to invalidate expired items?

That lead me to question my solution. Would you consider my solution a good practice?

P.S. I'm willing to switch to other caching solutions, if necessary.

Comment: Caffeine, like Guava, does not create threads so it cannot schedule work outside of user activity. Both would require calling `cleanUp` periodically. `CacheWriter` would provide safer semantics for write-behind, though. Scheduling semantics could do done via a Java 9 feature ([#195](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/195)) and I'll prioritize looking into providing interfaces to take advantage of that while being JDK8 compatible.

Comment: That is possible in [cache2k](https://cache2k.org) by adding a synchronous expiry listener e.g. `builder.Cache2kBuilder.addListener(new CacheEntryExpiredListener() ...)` and keeping sharp expiry off with `builder.sharpExpiry(false)`. However, cache2k uses one thread per cache for the expiration, that could become a bottleneck, if you need more than one expiry operation in parallel on the database. Your use case is a good example. I will keep that in mind for further development directions.

Comment: @yaseco This capability has been released in Caffeine 2.8. Simply specify `Caffeine.scheduler(Scheduler.systemScheduler())` (if JDK9+) in your cache builder and it will remove the expired entry promptly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the Ehcache with write-behind. It is for sure more setup effort but it is working quite well

Comment: I don't think Ehcache has scheduled expiration with write-behind. Expiration is implemented lazily by polluting the cache with dead entries and relying on size eviction to discard them eventually.